# How to create geography object by two pairs lat and long?

Tags: t-sql, spatial

I am first time trying the spatial types of T-SQL And the problem is that I don't know how to verify is point belong to circle which is defined by two pairs of points (lat1, long1; lat2, long2)

I tried to create the geography object:

```
declare @p1 geography = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(51,067222 -114,110043)',4326);
```

Neither of this code works:

declare @p1 geography = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(51,067222 -114,110043)',4326);
declare @p2 geography = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(51,100004 -113,850491)',4326);

```
declare @g, @g2 Geometry
set @g = 'Point(51,067222 -114,110043)';
set @g2 = 'Point(51,100004  -113,850491)';
select @g.STBuffer(@g2)
```

but without success.

Please don't kill me, I am trying this first time ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually found the answer. (NOTE: STContains works ONLY in MS SQL Server 2012 or greater)

```
-- First point
declare @p1 geography = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-114.110043 51.067222)', 4326);

-- Second point
declare @p2 geography = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-113.850491 51.100004)', 4326);

-- Find the distance between points in meters
declare @distanceInMeters float = @p1.STDistance(@p2);

-- Create circle geography object
declare @cicleGeography geography = @p1.STBuffer(@distanceInMeters)


declare @p3 geography = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-112.850491 51.100004)', 4326);

-- Returns true if the third point is inside the circle
select Id, @cicleGeography.STContains(@p3)
```

Very easy :)

Comment: When using `geography`, the tough part to remember is that points are defined as `longitude,latitude` because longitude is the X axis. At least in the US, we always think of the coords as "lat/long" and unlearning that is hard.

Comment: Further note: `STContains()` is only available in SQL Server 2012 and up. I tried on 2008R2 and it failed.

Comment: Yes, I used SQL Server 2012 on Azure

Answer (score 0):

Glad you found your own answer.  As an alternative, you can also use STIntersects() or STWithin().  For further reading / learning, I've also used an alternative for creating points using lat/long order..

```
-- First point
declare @p1 geography = geography::Point(51.067222, -114.110043, 4326);

-- Second point
declare @p2 geography = geography::Point(51.100004, -113.850491, 4326);

-- Find the distance between points in meters
declare @distanceInMeters float = @p1.STDistance(@p2);

-- Create circle geography object
declare @cicleGeography geography = @p1.STBuffer(@distanceInMeters)


declare @p3 geography = geography::Point(51.100004, -112.850491, 4326);

-- Returns true if the third point is inside the circle
select @id, @cicleGeography.STIntersects(@p3)

-- OR Alternatively
select @id, @cicleGeography.STWithin(@p3)
```